# Mapbox v10 iOS How to remove Annotation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapbox

i started writing a Project with Mapbox Support and added a Polyline.
Then i append a second Polyline to the array and both are shown up on the mapView.
But i cant figure out how to remove an Annotation.

```
        let firstPolyLineCoordinates = [
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48, 8),
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49, 9)
        ]

        let secondPolyLineCoordinates = [
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47, 8),
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(49.5, 9)
        ]

        // Create the line annotation.
        var firstPolyLineAnnotation = PolylineAnnotation(lineCoordinates: firstPolyLineCoordinates)
        firstPolyLineAnnotation.lineColor = StyleColor(.red)
        firstPolyLineAnnotation.lineWidth = 2

        var secondPolyLineAnnotation = PolylineAnnotation(lineCoordinates: secondPolyLineCoordinates)
        secondPolyLineAnnotation.lineColor = StyleColor(.blue)
        secondPolyLineAnnotation.lineWidth = 2

        // Create the `PolylineAnnotationManager` which will be responsible for handling this annotation
        let polyLineAnnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.makePolylineAnnotationManager()

        // Add the annotation to the manager.
        polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations = [firstPolyLineAnnotation]

        polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations.append(secondPolyLineAnnotation)
```

The Mapbox Docu says:
To remove a single annotation from an annotation manager, remove it from the annotations array.

https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/annotations/annotations/#removing-annotations

but there is no polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations.remove(name_of_annotation)
like the polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations.append(secondPolyLineAnnotation)

there is only a polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations.removeAll()
but i dont wont to remove both (or all polylines)...

is there any hint?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `init(id:lineCoordinates:)` PolylineAnnotation initialiser you can set the `id`. Then you can just use some standard Swift way to delete a particular element.

```
let myID = "bongo" // id of annotation for deletion.
if let idx = polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == myID }) {
    polyLineAnnnotationManager.annotations.remove(at: idx)
}
```

Comment: Works like charm... Thanks for the hint with the "id" at initialization...